# How can I get rid of the old wood/furniture smell?

Tags: kitchens, odors

I've just bough a place, renovated it a bit. The kitchen looks to be in decent condition, but I get that smell of old wood/furniture. How do I get rid of that?

I mean it's only for month or two, I will replace the kitchen of course, can't do all at once.

Comment: Like a wood oil smell?  I'm assuming someone oiled the cabinets before it sold to make them look better.  At least you have that smell instead of mold and rotting food.

Comment: @diceless not sure what is it. But it is not too nice

Comment: To get rid of a smell you first need to identify where the smell is coming from.  Typically look first where there is a source of water, sink/under sink, around fridge and around dishwasher.  If none of those seem to be the source, look at the wood of the cabinets.  Look inside at the sides, shelves and under the drawers.  Look for any obvious discoloration and use your sense of smell as a guide.  Look at the counters and under the cooktop for any sources as well.